# HTML Email Image in Header for Mac Outlook shows up as attachment

Tags: html, macos, email, outlook

I was reading up on images in html emails and couldnt find a solution so I decided to ask on stack. So I have an html template with an image as the header of the email.  For some reason, on Windows OS Outlook, the image displays as it should, but on Mac Outlook, it shows the little square image not found icon and the intended image as an attachment to the email.  The image is currently referenced within the project by relative path: `src='image/logo'` type deal.  Online, some sources say to use an absolute path so I tried `src='http://absolute/path/image/logo'`, yet the result was the same. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use "external" images in emails. This is a security/anti-spam thing. Mail clients will **NOT** auto-retrieve remote resources anymore.  Either embed them directly into the email using data uris or as mime attachments that you refer to with `cid:` pseudo-urls

Comment: And there are _very_ good reasons for this. HTML-Emails are one of the major (and very unnecessary) threads of typical home PCs these days.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Content-Location MIME header of the image attachment?
Have you tried to refer to the images through the Content-ID header and `<img scr='cid:xyz'` in your HTML?